# Code Analysis detected errors. No code analysis issues were detected

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

[image]

No errors in the output window. No errors at all besides this.

Any experience similar to this? Do anyone know where I can look to see what errors code analysis are reporting?

Comment: Try creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, impossible.. What i need is a way to see what errors code analysis gets. I've tried to add tracing to fxcop.exe.config and set msbuild output verbosity to detailed. There must be a way to se why code analysis thinks it has errors?

Comment: Impossible? You've got the project/code files in front of you and can experiment with excising chunks of code to see when/if the error disappears. As opposed to the rest of us who you expect to perform debugging psychically?

Comment: I do not want you to debug my project. I wanted to know if someone had any experience with this that could help me. My project is to large.. and it only happens in the context of this solution. I need help how to address this problem, which log files to look in etc..

Answer (score 0):

Alright, If your code analysis is damaged, there is a way to repair it.
if your language is WYSIWYG type language then copy all the controls and forms and paste in a new project. just copy the code that you've written(not compiler) and paste into the new project.